# Finding Out Serial Port Address in Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port

I've CCT-910 serial port hub and wh EMP 800 coin acceptor. Coin acceptor is connected to hub, and hub to computer.

They're both using same serial port (/dev/ttyUSB0 in Ubuntu 14.04), but their addresses are different. On Windows I can find out the addresses with manufacturer's software, which shows that HUB's address is 80 and coin acceptor's address is 42.

I've added more devices but I need to get the address of each device on the hub. How can I do it on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Comment: how do you mean, they are both using /dev/ttyUSB0 but their addresses are different? How do you send something to /dev/ttyUSB0, address 42?

Comment: These devices communicate with ccTalk protocol. On this protocol, you specify the address (meaning the destination), create the package and send it. Check it out:

http://www.balda.ch/posts/2013/Aug/11/cctalk-part1/

Comment: Presumably, the manufacturer's software scans all addresses from 2 to 255 looking for a device.  This isn't a U&L question, but more of a "how do I program this device?" question. If you look at the CCT-910 website you'll find a Linux ccTalk SDK which may be a good starting point.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, there **isn't** a Linux SDK on the internet. Also that's not about programming the device, I can do it at this moment w/o problem. (It just basically "send this message which has a destination of this address, to that serial port") Problem is, I can't find a way to get the addresses of different devices, on the same serial port, in Linux.

Comment: It actually is about talking to the CCT-910 device. Good idea might be calling the manufacturer support to either get protocol description or the Linux SDK they advertise.